# Logically, why is $\frac{d}{dx}(\ln{x}) = \frac{d}{dx}(\ln{ax})$?

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

The proof of $\frac{d}{dx}(\ln{x}) = \frac{d}{dx}(\ln{ax})$ is pretty simple:
use chain rule, then the `a` constants cancel, leaving you with 1/x, which is also the derivative of ln(x).

-- Logically, how does this make sense?

The `a` constant would have an effect on the graph of ln(x). And if it does not, or if the constant only serves to vertically translate ln(x), why is that?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The derivative gives lots of information about the shape of a graph. Here, the graph y=ln(x) has a special shape such that horizontally stretching or compressing it (i.e. multiplying points’ distances to the y-axis) actually has the same effect as translating (shifting) the graph vertically.

Comment: It's desirable that the voters for closing, with reason duplicate, bring links confirming their position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the laws of logarithms, $\ln ax = \ln a + \ln x$. Since $\ln a$ is a constant, you're vertically translating the plot of $y = \ln x$. Intuitively, it should now be obvious the slope of the tangent at any given $x$ coordinate should not be changed by this translation.

Answer (score 5):

$\ln(ax) = \ln(a) + \ln(x)$ by the properties of the logarithm. Hence $\ln(ax) - \ln(x)$ is constant so the two functions have the same derivative.

Answer (score 2):

One more possible view is derivative of composition:
$$ \frac{d}{dx}(\ln{ax}) = \frac{d}{dt}(\ln{t})\big|_{t=xa} \cdot \frac{d}{dx}ax=\frac{1}{ax}\cdot a = \frac{1}{x}$$
using these formulas for explanation, we can say that as far as the derivative of the logarithm shrinks, the same derivative of the linear function sprains.

Comment: Down voter is welcome for constructive critique, if have any, especially, as answer is correct.